# How to launch IPython while showing line numbers at the prompt?

Tags: ipython

I launch IPython in a script via: `start_ipython(config=cfg)` . `cfg` currently consists of modifications to `HistoryAccessor.hist_file`, `InteractiveShell.banner1`... but I can't find anything in the [documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/options/terminal.html) which relates to line numbers at the prompt. Currently, the prompt appears without line numbers as shown. IPython 7.2.0

[image]

If I run IPython from the command line (as opposed to from the above script), the line numbers appear as expected
[image]

Comment: In the second case `IPython` is processing the input and output; it's the interactive shell.  In the first case, `IPython` is a module that you've imported.  Input/output (the REPL loop) is still the basic python one.  You can access some `IPython` functions with `IPython....` syntax, just as you would with any other imported module, but it isn't acting as an interactive shell.

Comment: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/reference.html#embedding - shows how to start the interactive IPython session after the import.  `IPython.start_ipython(argv=[])` or `IPython.embed()`.

Comment: @hpaulj Perhaps I wasn't clear from the example. The prompt `>>>` was *after* I had already run `start_ipython`. I only got `>>>` and no lines numbers. (The text `import IPython` was simply for purposes of the screenshot so I could print out the version of IPython being used).